# Textboxes inside repeater items loosing their text properties after delete row

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, repeater, viewstate

I have a repeater and it's data is being bound on the page load. Also the controls inside repeater is being created on page load dynamically (textbox, dropsownlist etc.)

User fills the textboxes and when he wants to delete a row in the repeater he can deletes the entry on the datasource(datasource is being retrieved from a web service). After delete operation, repeater is rebound to datasource.

At this point the text values of textboxes which ordered after deleted row is disappearing. Only the textboxes which are before deleted row is protecting their text values.

For example: I have 5 rows in the repeater. I fill all of the textboxes inside rows. When I delete the 3rd row, 1st 2nd rows' textboxes' texts  are appearing again but 4th and 5th rows' textboxes' texts are coming empty.

I think this is happening because mismatch of the viewstate and controls' ids but how can I prevent this and get all the textboxes' texts after delete?

Comment: Can you post some code? We may try to fix the existing code rather than writing everything from scratch.

Comment: You're probably missing a `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` check somewhere in one of the page cycle events. But like comment above, we need to see some code.